# Installing ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.6 for use with ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to use JS API v4.x on Federated ArcGIS Server, but I am having problem regarding setting up the JS API v4.x.

I am deploying arcgis javascript library and sdk v4.6 in an IIS server locally (no internet connection) using [this tutorial](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011974). While following the tutorial I have figured out that it might be only for v3.x because

While configuring

```
Javascript API CSS2 URL
```

to

```
http://myhost.example.com/arcgis_js_api/library/3.16/3.16/esri/css/esri.css
```

I realize that there is no *esri.css* file found in **v4.x**, rather I found *main.css* and *view.css*. So for now I use *main.css* as Javascript API CSS2 URL.

[image: Configuration]

Now I publish a testService in arcgis server. When I try to view the service unfortunately I see blank page. Below is my network log having javascript loading errors

[image: Network Log]

It seems that the two javascript (*ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer.js* and *ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer.js*) files are missing. I checked that these files are only present in v3.x not in v4.x. Now if I copy these file from v3.x to v4.x I got many other errors w.r.t. other javascript files loading issue.

Can we deploy v4.x locally (no internet) on server and, if yes, then am I following right [tutorial](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011974) or am I missing any step while configuring ?

I downloaded v4.6 from [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/downloads/apis-and-sdks?product=javascript&version=4.6)

I have also [posted same question to GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/message/750010-re-how-to-install-the-javascript-api-v46-for-use-with-arcgis-for-server)

Comment: Link-only answers are likely to be deleted because the content is elsewhere, but this the first link-only question I've ever encountered.  Please take the [Tour] to better understand our purpose here.

Comment: @Vince question updated

Comment: You're following a 3.x tutorial and the linked question states that it isn't possible. If you want to hold out for an answer from Esri, you probably should ask Tech Support.

Comment: First I couldn't found anyother tutorial for v4.x for deployment. I also followed the installation guide (arcgis_js_v46_api > install.html), but no luck.

Comment: ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer and ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer are renamed in arcgis js v4 as, BaseDynamicLayer and TileLayer